# Force drawstart on mousedown in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

The dragstart event of a Draw interaction does not fire until a full click is registered. How can I force the interaction to start drawing when the browser catches the mousedown event?

on mousedown I add the draw interaction

```
this.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();     
this.vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: this.vectorSource});
this.map.addLayer(this.vectorLayer);    

let drawObj = {
    source: this.vectorSource,
    type: 'LineString'
}

this.drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw(drawObj);
this.map.addInteraction(this.drawInteraction);
```

Then how do I force it to start drawing?

I tried

- this.drawInteraction.setActive(true),
- dispatchEvent('drawstart') on the map, layer, and interaction.
- dispatchEvent('pointerdown') in conjunction with using the draw
  interaction's condition property

Comment: You can use `drawInteraction.extend` similar to https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-yhmbl?file=/main.js

Comment: You could also use `drawInteraction.appendCoordinates` https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-features-forked-0kjfv?file=/main.js

Comment: Thanks for that, it's been a week staring at the docs and somehow never saw "extend" even though it explicitly says exactly what I was looking for lol.